# How to typecast a float tensor into long tensor without rounding error?

Tags: python-3.x, torch, tensor

I have a float tensor made by multiplying a matrix by its inverse (so the identity matrix). When I convert to int, it is not the identity matrix, i.e, 1.0000e00 becomes 0.  I need a way to typecast with rounding.

I have tried typecasting using .int() and .long() but they round to zero. Specifically:

```
I = tensor([[ 1.0000e+00,  1.1921e-07, -1.1921e-07],
        [-5.9605e-08,  1.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
        [-2.9802e-08,  0.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00]])
I = I.long()
print(I)
```

gives:

```
tensor([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]])
```

What should happen is that `print(I)` returns

```
tensor([[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]])
```

What line of code will change my tensor into what I want? It should only take one line.

Comment: Try updating your pytorch. The code above works with the expected results on my machine.

Comment: I'm using torch, which i think may be different.  For example, before this code I type `from torch import tensor`

Comment: I know that; when I run this exact code I get your intended results.

Comment: Huh, youre right.  I tried again in Python3 and it worked fine. I initially had this problem when doing it in Jupyter, so maybe that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is restart your Jupyter kernal, or plug into python3.  For whatever reason, this error happened in a Jupyter notebook.